# Swap bytes in a DWORD

Tags: c++

I have a `DWORD`, e.g: `0x0A0B0C0D`. I want to obtain `0x0D0C0B0A`.

I usually use the `BSWAP` assembly instruction but I am using a compiler that doesn't support a built-in assember.

Comment: Why do not just use plain byte shifting and then and to combine all the bytes?  Do you have any requirements in terms of performance?

Comment: As Necrolis said, please state which compiler you are using in the question statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new_dword = (dword & 0x000000ff) << 24 | (dword & 0x0000ff00) << 8 |
    (dword & 0x00ff0000) >> 8 | (dword & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

Answer (score 6):

And what is this compiler? most *decent* compilers these days support a bswap intrinsic, GCC has a few solutions [here](http://patches.libav.org/patch/2529/), or the [plain builtin list](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

MSVC has `_byteswap_*` in its [RTL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx)(which get optimized to intrinsic form), and ICC includes the `_bswap*` intrinsics.

Answer (score 5):

You could use e.g. [`htonl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you don't want to do the bit-twiddling your self.

Comment: +1: One question though, would the OP be able to `#include <arpa/inet.h>`? :)

Comment: @EitanT very funny i might add

Comment: Depends on the platform - `htonl` is a no-op on big-endian systems.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2563/

Consider a routine that manually reorders the bits.
This is pretty much guaranteed to be maximally slow compared to the alternatives, which may not suit your needs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int rearrange(unsigned int val);

int main() {
    unsigned int a = 0xa0b0c0d0;
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase
              << a << '\n'
              << rearrange(a) << std::endl;
}

unsigned int rearrange(unsigned int val) {
    return (val & 0xff000000) >> CHAR_BIT * 3 |
           (val & 0x00ff0000) >> CHAR_BIT |
           (val & 0x0000ff00) << CHAR_BIT |
           (val & 0x000000ff) << CHAR_BIT * 3;
}
```

Outputs

```
0xa0b0c0d0
0xd0c0b0a0
```